# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.DataObject' to type "Product"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, casting

i tired to cast an object to Product in DragDrop, the Product type is an EntityFrameWork type please help me what i should do?
my code it is looks like:

```
void IDroppingTarget.Drop(GAMA.gpf.Utils.DragDrop.IDropInformation dropInfo)
    {
            // ...
            Product t = (Product)dropInfo.Data; // Data is containign the product that 
                                                // draged from the sourcecollection
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast just like that. You need to use [GetDataPresent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [GetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597427%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var dataObject = dropInfo.Data;
if(dataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(Product)))
{
    Product t = (Product)dataObject.GetData(typeof(Product)); 
}
```